# How to tell bash to repeat a script until satisfactory, then output the finished product

Tags: linux, bash, bc

I'm looking to repeat this code until I stop it, either by setting a time for which it repeats, pressing ^c, or set number of iterations, and then output the result of repeating it. The code should feed into itself, such that inputting the variables 5 and 2 the first time would result in restarting the script with 5 and 2.25 as the variables. The script helps determine the square root of a number, with one guess.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Please enter the number you need to find the square root for and press [ENTER]: "
read fin
echo -n "Please enter guess and press [ENTER]: "
read gues
var=$(echo "$fin/$gues" | bc -l )
var1=$(echo "$var+$gues" | bc -l )
var2=$(echo "$var1/2" | bc -l )
echo $var2
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to put that code into an infinite loop, such as:

```
while 1; do
  # Rest of code
  ...
done
```

In order to stop when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is hit, what you're actually doing is to trap a signal (concretely, `SIGINT`). You'd need to define a `trap` so it triggers when you hit that combination of keys.

For more info about traps, you can have a look [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html), which includes a `SIGINT` example and how you can print anything after catching it.

> trap [COMMANDS] [SIGNALS]
>
> This instructs the trap command to catch the listed SIGNALS, which may be signal names with or without the SIG prefix, or signal numbers. If a signal is 0 or EXIT, the COMMANDS are executed when the shell exits. If one of the signals is DEBUG, the list of COMMANDS is executed after every simple command. A signal may also be specified as ERR; in that case COMMANDS are executed each time a simple command exits with a non-zero status. Note that these commands will not be executed when the non-zero exit status comes from part of an if statement, or from a while or until loop. Neither will they be executed if a logical AND (&&) or OR (||) result in a non-zero exit code, or when a command's return status is inverted using the ! operator.

Comment: I suppose that the end combination of keys is optional, or maybe could be set to do the code for a set number of seconds

Comment: It actually traps SIGNALs. So, if you're able to generate a signal recognized by bash, it's OK. That would be the case of Ctrl+C, which indeed produces a `SIGINT` to the script, but not *all* combinations produce a signal. You can, however, send a script any signal from other bash script, but that would involve knowing the PID of the receiving bash script, which can be tedious. You could also do `X` iterations (with a variable which counts how much times has it been run) inside the loop and then exit the loop.

Comment: a set number sounds like a perfect match for what I need